# How to get the Client ID of asp.net control that is inaccessible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have a few custom controls I need to access in a javascript function, but in my script, it says my controls are not declared or inaccessible due to protection level. This is what my current script looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        function ddl_AutoSchedule_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventargs) {
            var date_DueDate = document.getElementById('<%= date_DueDate.ClientID %>');
            var date_PlannedStart = document.getElementById('<%= date_PlannedStart.ClientID %>');
            var date_PlannedFinish = document.getElementById('<%= date_PlannedFinish.ClientID %>');
            date_DueDate.textContent = new Date() + sender.value;
            date_PlannedStart.textContent = new Date();
            date_PlannedFinish.textContent = new Date() + sender.value;
        }
    </script>
```

The custom controls I'm trying to access are nested within a few other elements such as a form view and various divs. I've tried going down the heirarchy such as

```
document.getElementById('<%= formView_Control.ClientID %>').getElementById('<%= date_DueDate.ClientID %>');
```

and that doesn't seem to work either. Any ideas or foolproof ways to get these client ids?

Comment: Oh, hang on, are you trying to get the ID of Telerik controls? Static won't work for them.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Oh no :( Do you know how I can access them otherwise? I've been grinding my gears for days on this

Comment: By "custom control", do you mean a User Control (with a .ascx file extension) or a Telerik control?

Comment: @AndrewMorton A User Control made from a telerik RadDatePicker specifically

Comment: And are you using a Master Page? That is, is the User Control on the Master Page?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, but the User Control is on the same page as the js function. Not on the master page

Comment: The user control will have been declared in the page with something like `<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/SomeControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="SomeControl" %>`. So, you need to use `SomeControl.YourTelerikControl.ClientID` to refer to YourTelerikControlID. Does that seem to make sense? (You might need more nesting if the control is within other controls.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes it is declared on the page as you mentioned.

If the control on my page is date_DueDate, the name of the user control .ascx is custom_date.ascx and inside of that control there is a RadDatePicker with RadDatePicker1 as the id. Would the proper syntax be, custom_date.RadDatePicker1.ClientID? And if so, how would it know which control on my page to modify if I had multiple 'custom_date's on the page?

Comment: You can see why I went with "Static" when I could, lol. You should have a different TagName for each instance of the usercontrol, so `custom_dateFirst.RadDatePicker1.ClientID`, `custom_dateSecond.RadDatePicker1.ClientID`, etc. (preferably named more appropriately).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yeah it's definitely a pain lol. Unfortunately we've come full circle and those 'custom_dateFirst' controls, or in my example, 'date_DueDate', are not accessible. in document.getElementById('<%= date_DueDate.RadDatePicker1.ClientID %>'). date_DueDate is said to be "not declared, or inaccessible due to it's protection level"

Comment: Do you have [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) enabled? It would hopefully persuade Visual Studio to be able to give you auto-complete guidance for the control reference. I don't think that FindControl will help, because there are multiple instances of the same control on the page. If it gets ridiculously difficult, you could make multiple usercontrols instead of re-using the same one, but that would not be ideal.

Comment: @AndrewMorton No luck with that either :(, thanks for all the suggestions tho...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ID of the Telerik date-picker in user-control is `tdp` ,

```
var date_DueDate =$telerik.findControl(document,"date_DueDate_tdp").get_selectedDate();
```

Recardless of any surrounding controls around the user-control or around the original date-picker in user-control.